# Navigation bar made of images

Tags: html, css

I have five different images being used as buttons for my website's navigation. I want them to be inline horizontally and centred in the browser window. They looked fine until I added code to have text appear under each button when hovering over each image. The buttons are now all aligned vertically in the middle of the window.

In html file:

```
   <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
            <div class="about">
            <li><input type="image" src="image.png" id="aboutPage" onClick = 'aboutPage()'/></li>
            <p class = "text1"> About </p>
            </div>

            <div class="resume">
            <li><input type="image" src="image.png" id="resumePage" onClick = 'resumePage()'/></li>
            <p class = "text2"> Resume </p>
            </div>

            <div class="home">
            <li><input type="image" src="image.png" id="homePage" onClick = 'homePage()'/></li>
            <p class = "text3"> Home </p>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio">
            <li><input type="image" src="image.png" id="portfolioPage" onClick = 'portfolioPage()'/></li>
            <p class = "text4"> Portfolio </p>
            </div>

            <div class="contact">
            <li><input type="image" src="image.png" id="contactPage" onClick = 'contactPage()'/></li>
            <p class = "text5"> Contact </p>
            </div>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

In CSS file:

```
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.nav .container {
   font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.nav .container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav .container li {
  display: inline;
}
```

The following is a sample of the hover code for each image:

```
.nav .container .about .text1 {
   position:relative;
   bottom:0px;
   text-align: center;
   visibility: hidden;
}

.nav .container .about:hover .text1{
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I have a few remarks when it comes to your markup. I know this is not code review, and not entirely relevant to the question, but I just can't help myself when I look at the HTML:

- a `div.nav` just screams to me that you in fact want to use a `nav`
- that `div.container` seems obsolote to me, and just adds markup. If you realy need the container class (for css or js reasons), why not add it to the `ul` in stead.
- an `ul` can only have `li` elements as direct child, so those `div` elements should become a child of the `li` in stead of a parent.
- why are you using (the very rare) `input[type=image]` elements, in stead of the usual `<a><img></a>`? It just seems strange.
- using a different class for each text seems to serve no purpose. It just makes your code harder to maintain and your css a lot more verbose. I wonder if you need a class at all, but If you have a good reason, at least use the same class for all the text blocks.

Taking those remarks into account, my markup would look something like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul class='container'>
        <li>
            <a href='#'>
                <img src='' alt='do not forget your alt, especially for nav!' />
                <p>text</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then for your actual question, I am not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but [this is what I came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/q4dxt3ox/). The css looks something like this.

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:'Shift', sans-serif;
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-weight: lighter;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav li {
    margin: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav p {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
nav a:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Note that I went for `opacity` in stead of `visibility` because that allows you to add a transition, which I find to give a much nicer experience. You should be able to use visibility as well though (or just remove the transition) for an instant state switch.

I hope this puts you on the right track. Let me know if I misunderstood anything, or if you want me to explain further.